# Как использовать перенос строки в левой части sed?

Tags: linux, shell, sed

Отслеживаю логи через `tailf` (`tail -f`). Для удобства отображения хотелось бы после каждой строки добавлять пустую строку.

Например:

```
$ tailf /var/log/some.log
log1
log2
log3

$ tailf /var/log/some.log | magic
log1

log2

log3
```

Пробовал через [sed](http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/tutorials/sedfaq.txt) двумя способами, но получаю то же без изменений. Идея в том, чтобы поматчить перенос строки и заменить его на два переноса. Общий синтаксис такой: `sed 's/substitute_this/to_this/g'`

Способ 1: вставить перенос строки как `$'\n'`.

```
$ tailf /var/log/some.log | sed "s/$'\n'/test/g"
log1
log2
log3
```

Похоже, что `$'\n'` не матчится на переносы строк в моем логе.

Способ 2: вставить перенос строку как перенос строки при вводе команды:

```
$ tailf /var/log/some.log | sed "s/
> /test/g"
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unterminated `s' command

$ tailf /var/log/some.log | sed "s/\
/test/g"
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

Если бы это был shell-скрипт, можно было бы [использовать хак](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9403076/2790048):

```
newline='
'
```

Но я-то хочу "на ходу" использовать. Сделать фукцию или alias тоже не подойдёт, т.к. я работаю с большим количеством хостов и не имею возможности индивидуально настраивать `.bashrc`.

Собственно, вопрос: что должно быть на месте `magic`?

Comment: `sed "s/$/\n/g"`?

Comment: @BOPOH `sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unknown option to `s'
`

Comment: ничего не понял, у меня все отработало как надо, может как-то не так сделали? дистрибутив какой? я на убунте проверял. Т.е. вот такая строчка у меня выдает как надо: `tailf /var/log/apache2/access.log | sed "s/$/\n/g"`

Comment: @BOPOH действительно работает, я немного другое пробовал. Тогда вопрос: что такое `$`, почему оно матчится как перенос строки? Понятно, что в правой части `\n` становится переносом строки.

Comment: `^` как и `$` - это не символ, а положение в тексте. Пложение нельзя заменить, но туда что-то можно вставить. Т.е. заменяя `$` чем-то, вы на самом деле вставляете в конец это "что-то"

Comment: @BOPOH спасибо. Опубликуйте ответ что ли )

Comment: на хороший ответ нужно время (которого обычно нет), а если вы прочитаете [эту книжку](http://www.books.ru/books/regulyarnye-vyrazheniya-3-e-izdanie-592346/), то сможете сами написать неплохой ответ )

Comment: кстати, насчет последнего редактирования вопроса: не уверен, что sed получает строку, у которой есть "перенос строки". Скорее всего у него на входе просто строка вида *текст* (если быть точнее: *{НАЧАЛО_СТРОКИ}текст{КОНЕЦ_СТРОКИ}* или *^текст$*), т.е. никаких переводов там нет, они обрезаются на этапе транспортировки через pipe (хотя могу ошибаться, здесь я не силен)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36348/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and-bopoh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Еще вариант с sed:

`tailf foo.log`

```
init.lxc 1455930731.917 ERROR    lxc_initutils - initutils.c:mount_fs:36 - failed to mount /proc : Device or resource busy
init.lxc 1455930758.674 ERROR    lxc_initutils - initutils.c:mount_fs:36 - failed to mount /proc : Device or resource busy
init.lxc 1455986152.381 ERROR    lxc_initutils - initutils.c:mount_fs:36 - failed to mount /proc : Device or resource busy
init.lxc 1455986234.349 ERROR    lxc_initutils - initutils.c:mount_fs:36 - failed to mount /proc : Device or resource busy
```

`tailf foo.log | sed 'a\ '`

```
init.lxc 1455930731.917 ERROR    lxc_initutils - initutils.c:mount_fs:36 - failed to mount /proc : Device or resource busy

init.lxc 1455930758.674 ERROR    lxc_initutils - initutils.c:mount_fs:36 - failed to mount /proc : Device or resource busy

init.lxc 1455986152.381 ERROR    lxc_initutils - initutils.c:mount_fs:36 - failed to mount /proc : Device or resource busy

init.lxc 1455986234.349 ERROR    lxc_initutils - initutils.c:mount_fs:36 - failed to mount /proc : Device or resource busy
```

Comment: Видимо `a` это add.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: да, всё верно. Команда `a\ ` добавляет новую строку с содержимым, которое указано после \, в данном случае просто добавляется пустая строка с пробелом.

Comment: Приму этот вариант как более лаконичный. )

Comment: Уже раз 15 воспользовался. У меня вечно в логах записи на 2-5 строк)

Answer (score 1):

вам надо в конце строки (а *sed* работает именно **построчно**) вставлять символ перевода строки `\n`.

якорем (метасимволом, квантификатором), обозначающим конец строки, в большинстве диалектов регулярных выражений обычно служит символ `$`:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/some.log | sed 's/$/\n/'
```

для изоляции от «вмешательства» оболочки программу для *sed* лучше заключать в одинарные кавычки (да, `s/$/\n/` — это именно программа, **интерпретируемая** программой *sed*).