# Как добавить несколько строк после заданного слова?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

В файл header.php на следующую строку после тэга  нужно добавить
несколько строк, например

```
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//themes.googleusercontent.com">
```

Если добавлять 1 строки - все ок, но стоит добавить еще одну

```
sed '/<head>/ a \
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//themes.googleusercontent.com">
' header.php > header2.php
```

> sed: -e выражение #1, символ 70: неизвестная команда: `<'

И можно ли обойтись без создания выходного файла?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/498234/178576

Comment: перевод каретки надо записать в виде `\n`, параметр `-i` sed заставляет его переписать исходный файл

Comment: Испробовал разные комбинации - не получается. sed: -e выражение #1, символ 72: неизвестная команда: `<'

Comment: Если я правильно понял проблему, то после `href="//fonts.googleapis.com">` надо добавить обратный слэш " \".

Comment: Эта проблема на языке программирования типа bash просто так не решается. Вам нужен парсер XML. Пользуйтесь python, к примеру. Там есть отличный модуль lxml (ElementTree).

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день. Если правильно понял задачу, то решить ее можно примерно так:

```
sed -i '/<head>/ a \<link rel=\"dns-prefetch\" href=\"\/\/fonts.googleapis.com\"\>\n\<link rel=\"dns-prefetch\" href=\"\/\/themes.googleusercontent.com\"\>' header.php
```

Answer (score 1):

При вашем подходе очевидно, что будут ошибки, так как нет символа перенова в shellе.
Ваш пример нужно переделать с:

```
sed '/<head>/ a \
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//themes.googleusercontent.com">
' header.php > header2.php
```

на

```
sed -i '/<head>/ a \
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.googleapis.com"> \
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//themes.googleusercontent.com"> \
' header.php
```

В таком случае промежуточный файл создаваться не будет, будет сразу перезаписан файл.